# How can I check out file with the commit time

Tags: java, svnkit

I wrote a java program that using the SVNKit. The timestamp of checked out file is  system time ,instead of  the commit time 。How  can I check out file with the commit time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [ISVNOptions#setUseCommitTimes()](http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/ISVNOptions.html). From there:

> Enables or disables the commit-times option. The commit-times option
>   makes checkout/update/switch/revert operations put last-committed
>   timestamps on every file they touch.
>
> This option corresponds to the 'use-commit-times' option that can be
>   found in the SVN's config file under the [miscellany] section.